# Phusion Passenger Standalone Meteor Tutorial Fails with Spawning Error

Tags: ubuntu, meteor, passenger, phusion

I've tried the tutorial [Quickstart: Meteor + Phusion Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/start/meteor.html) on Ubuntu 18.04 and 16.04 as well as Centos 7. In all cases I get something very similar to the following Ubuntu 18.04 error:

```
pp 4831 output: !> I have control 1.0
[ E 2018-05-20 20:58:24.3092 4797/Te age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:221 ]: Could not spawn process for application /home/family/leaderboard: A timeout error occurred while spawning an application process.
  Error ID: f3f0b77b
```

I've tried increasing the spawn timeout, but it's as though Meteor isn't being launched. The Leaderboard Meteor app, as recommended by the Phusion tutorial, works just fine with Meteor.

What can I try next?

Comment: How does your app differ from the leaderboard app? Any errors on the app when starting manually as node application? Edit: any logs that could contain some more info?

Comment: Hi Jankapunkt, my problem is with the Leaderboard app - the tutorial doesn't work. (My own app behaves in the same way though and it uses the current version of Meteor.)
Are you using Phusion Passenger with Meteor? If so, which version of Meteor and Phusion Passenger?
I've have a feeling that as soon as I see the line...
"App <number> output: !> I have control 1.0"
...its game over.
As the problem seems to be a spawning failure I've played with the "--spawn-method direct" flag and also increased timeouts by using the "--start-timeout" and "--max-preloader-idle-time" to no avail.

Answer (score -1):

This should be fixed in Passenger 5.3.2.

Comment: Is there no more context? Do you have a link to the change that resolved this?